# Passing props from child to parent components in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a select box component that has 2 options, I want to show an input field when the 2nd choice in the first select box is chosen, it is working as the condition is in the child component, i want to make it up one level in the parent component, can someone help me in that?

**Parent Component**

```
const GenderOptions = [
  {label: "Male", value: "Male"},
  {label: "Female", value: "Female"},
];

  <SelectBox
       name="Gender"
       label="Gender"
       options={GenderOptions}
  />
```

**Child Component**

```
 export function SelectBox({...props}: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>) {
  const {
    register,
    setValue,
  } = useFormContext();
  const { ref, ...rest } = register(name, {
    onChange: props.onChange,
  });
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string | undefined>("");
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={fieldId}>{label}</label>
       <ComboBox
         id={fieldId}
         placeholder="Please Choose..."
         options={options}
         mode="select"
         onSelected={item => {
            setValue(name, item?.value);
            setInputValue(item?.value);
         }}  
       />  
    </div>
    {inputValue === "Female" && (
       <InputBox
          type="text"
          name="Age"
          label="Age"
       />
     )}
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You parent should provide a function to the child, and the child should use it to provide information to the parent.

Move your useState to the parent and provide the update function to the child